# Scalability of LanguageTool

Tags: scalability, languagetool

I'd like to scale the [LanguageTool HTTP Server](https://languagetool.org/) so it can handle a large number of user requests at a time and process very large texts. Which is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of LanguageTool. The short answer is that you can scale it like any HTTP service: run several instances and put them behind a load balancer. As LanguageTool server has no state, this should be easy. The longer answer requires more information: how long are the documents and in which languages are they? Do you need spell checking or only the features that go beyond spell checking? LanguageTool is much slower for some languages than for others. For example, English is quite slow, most languages with a low number of rules (see https://languagetool.org/languages/) are faster.